# Getting variable from included php file

Tags: php

I have the following code:

**db.php**

```
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "database";
$dbuser = "admin";
$dbpass = "12345";

global $db;

$db = new mysqli();

$db->connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
$db->set_charset("utf8");
```

**random-file.php**

```
require_once 'db.php';

doSomething($db, $value1, $value2);
```

As you can see I am trying to pass the $db variable in random-file.php as a parameter. This $db variable is defined in db.php.

It all works well with PHP 5.4.34 and I have no problem at all. BUT: If I run this code with PHP 5.6.3 I get the following error message:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: db
```

What is wrong with my code setup? How can I achieve that my code works BOTH with PHP 5.4 and 5.6?

Comment: Why is `global` used in that context ?

Comment: I always use it, just by default...

Comment: Maybe it's time to learn about [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: Everything is OK, error occurs because You dont have variable called `$db` in place where You call it.

Comment: Best practices aside, that use of `global` works on my computer. What do you get with a `print_r($db)` right before the function call?.

Answer (score 1):

The global variable you used is not necessary. You should opt for passing arguments in this scenario.

```
function db_conn($dbhost, $dbname, $dbuser, $dbpass) {
    $db = new mysqli();
    $db->connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
    $db->set_charset("utf8");
    return $db;
}

$db_handle = db_conn("localhost", "database", "admin", "12345");
doSomething($db_handle, $value1, $value2);
```

You pass all your database details to the function directly, and the function returns the handle you then use throught your file.